# Typescript function type order issue with |

Tags: typescript

I just needed to type an argument of one of my functions. Not a very uncommon task, but this time it could be two types, a string or a function. So I tried

```
function listen (event: string | () => void): void {}
```

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZyogFADwFyIYBOMYA5ogD7YCUiAvAHyIBucMAJjQW54gN4BYAFAiAvkA)

[image]

This gives an error. Typescript doesn't understand anymore whats going on.

However, one way to fix this is to swap them

```
 function listen (event: () => void | string): void {}
```

Well I guess it makes sense. Can someone explain to me whats going on here or point me to the right documentation

Comment: `() => void | string` means `() => (void | string)`. You want `(() => void) | string` or `string | (() => void)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like, inside a type expression, the parser expects `(` to open a group only.

Wrap the function type in parentheses and it will work.